# Email address is invalid response from campaign monitor api in meteor js

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, meteor, campaign-monitor

I am having trouble in a [meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) project. I am trying to add a email address to a subscriber list using the [campaign monitor api](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/api/subscribers/). I am using a npm package called [createsend-node](https://github.com/nufyoot/createsend-node), it is a wrapper of the api. I have successfully added a subscriber to a list using the api, however when I try to fire a meteor server method from a form submit event the api kicks back a `email address not valid response code 1`. I will include my code below. When I added the subscriber manually without the method it is successful. The email address was a string when I passed it manually, which is the same for the method. Code Below.

**html**

```
<template name="info">
  <h2>Signup For Our Newsletter</h2>

  <form id="cm-subscribe">

    <input field name="email" type="email" value="email">
    <input field name="name" type="text" value="name">

    <input type="submit">
  </form>

</template>
```

**Client side js**

```
Template.info.events({
  'submit #cm-subscribe'(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = event.target;
    var email = form.email.value;
    var name = form.name.value;
    console.log(email + " / " + name);
    Meteor.call('addSub', email, name);
  }
});
```

**Server side js**

```
Meteor.methods({
  addSub: function (name, email) {

    console.log(name);
    console.log(email);

    var listId = 'someid' // The ID of the list
    var details = {
      EmailAddress: email,
      Name: name,
      CustomFields: [
        { Key: 'CustomKey', Value: 'Some Value' }
      ]
    };

    api.subscribers.addSubscriber(listId, details, (err, res) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
    });

  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've reversed the arguments between the caller and the method.

```
Meteor.call('addSub', email, name)

Meteor.methods({
  addSub: function (name, email) {
```

Comment: A second set of eyes was all I needed. Thanks so simple.